# How to set MainLayout conditionally for a component in Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my `Blazor Server` project, I have a `MainLayout.razor` component which is a master layout for the whole application. On this MainLayout's `OnInitialized` event I'm checking the `authentication` state and only `authenticated` users can access the further components.

There is a FAQ `component` which should be accessible by `authenticated` and non-authenticated users as well. For both of such users, some functionality would be different.

I have created another Layout Component which doesn't need authentication.

Now I'm stuck at the point that how I can dynamically set the layout of the FAQ component according to authenticated and non-authenticated users.

**App.razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
 [CascadingParameter]
public Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationState { get; set; }

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    var authState = await AuthenticationState;
    if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Some functionality after login
    }
    else
    {
       //Navigate to the Login screen
    }

}
```

**TempLayout.razor** (this component to be used for non-authenticated users)

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

 <!--Start: Content-->
<div class="app-content container center-layout mt-2">
<div class="content-overlay"></div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header row">
    </div>
    @Body
</div>
```

Comment: does this link answer your question?https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39456

Comment: @RuikaiFeng This solution is for the whole application. I need a solution for one component only.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between authenticated and not authenticated users on your FAQ page? Doesn't the `<AuthorizeView>` component help you?

Answer (score 1):

Make two components; one for authenticated and other for un-authenticated users. Set different layout for each

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the app.razor in a authorizeView. This way you can aggregate to the correct layout depending on which autorization state you currently have.

OR

you use only one layout.razor and you make some conditional cshtml to show the correct layout.

As @ruikai_feng mentioned this might help you https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39456